# extract number in string with regex in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this string

```
url = "#AppDashboardPlace:p=io.transporterapp.deep.test1&amp;appid=4975603106871514996"
```

I would like to get `4975603106871514996`

I have tried that

```
url.to_s[/\appid\=(.*?)\&/, 1]
=> nil
```

Comment: `url[/(?<=appid=)(\d+)/]`

Comment: are u sure it's correct?

Comment: There was a typo; the edited one is surely correct.

Comment: you don't actually need the parens around the `\d+` since you're using the loosbehind assertion and not referencing any capture groups.

Comment: What are the rules for identifying the desired string? Must it be at the end of the string or be preceded by `appid=`, as in the example and by your regex? Must it be a certain length? Must it be the first or last substring containing digits? That’s what I mean by “rules”. If you do not state the rules readers must guess what they are.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Without knowing more about the *possible* inputs to the regex, there's no way to know.  We can assume its always got `appid=` in it, and then followed by digits to the end.  But maybe not.  If you want the digits at the end, then `url[/\d+$/]` is entirely sufficient, and will work even if the thing right before is not `appid=`.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex doesn't match because there's no `&` after the appid value. Try this:

```
url.to_s[/appid=(\d+)/,1]
```

If you left the matching part as `.*?` with nothing after it, it would match the minimum amount of the string possible, which is the empty string. If you know that the appid is the very end of the string, then you could use `.*` without the `?`, but it's best to be precise and specify that what you're looking for is a series of one or more (`+`) decimal digits (`\d`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String#match` with the \d regex matcher, for matching on `\d+`, which means one or more digit.

```
url = "#AppDashboardPlace:p=io.transporterapp.deep.test1&amp;appid=4975603106871514996"
match = url.match(/appid\=(\d+)/)
# => #<MatchData "appid=4975603106871514996" 1:"4975603106871514996">
puts match[0]
# => "appid=4975603106871514996"
puts match[1]
# => "4975603106871514996"
```